# Consecutive print on file using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

In a for loop, I want to print on a file the result of a calculation for each step. In C language `fprintf` it would have done automatically. Let us see this MWE:

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

outfile = Path("hello_world.csv")

x_n = 0

for t in np.arange(0, 100, 0.01):

   x_n = t+1
   
   pd.DataFrame([t, x_n]).T.to_csv(outfile, header=["t", "x"], index=False)
```

Of course in this way I obtain a file with only 2 values since, for each step, the previous values get overwritten.
My **aim** is having a file whose columns elements are the results of **each loop step**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify that you want to append the values, not overwrite them, using the [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) parameter.

```py
...
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

outfile = Path("./hello_world.csv")

x_n = 0

for t in np.arange(0, 100, 0.01):
    if not outfile.exists():
        pd.DataFrame([t, x_n]).T.to_csv(outfile, header=["t", "x"], index=False)
    else:
        # avoid appending the header
        pd.DataFrame([t, x_n]).T.to_csv(outfile, mode="a", index=False, header=False)
    x_n = t + 1

my_data = pd.read_csv(outfile)

print(my_data)
# Outputs
           t       x    
0       0.00    0.00    
1       0.01    1.00    
2       0.02    1.01    
3       0.03    1.02    
4       0.04    1.03    
...      ...     ...    
10995  99.95  100.94    
10996  99.96  100.95    
10997  99.97  100.96    
10998  99.98  100.97    
10999  99.99  100.98
```

Comment: of course I would add a printing on file before the loop. In this way the outfile exists and I can remove the `if` and the code would be more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a mismatch of the columns. The first appended column is now under the second one of the first call of `pd.DataFrame` and the second appended column is related to a new column. In fact when I call: `my_data = pd.read_csv(outfile)` I obtain the well known error `Error tokenizing data. C error...`

Comment: `index=False` was simply missing in the second statement, see my updated answer.